# Can Mathematica automatically submit a code for evaluation every 10 seconds?

Tags: scripting

I would like to automatize Mathematica to run the code:

```
[Geolocation]
```

every ten seconds. Is that possible?

I have searched online, but could not find any indications for that, so I wanted to ask the community here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check docs for `Refresh`.

Comment: Thanks Syed! ..

Comment: or ScheduledTask: `SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[MessageDialog["Hello"], {Quantity[10, "Seconds"], 10}]]`